# Unidentifiable body

Tags: crime

A man is under interrogation: he is a suspect in the case of his ex. She has disappeared a couple of weeks ago, and around the same time the police has found the remainders nearby. Surely, it is not possible to tell straight away from those remainders whether that's the girl or not (e.g. the face is burnt with fire or acid), so longer taking tests are required. It is still not clear whether that's the girl or not, and as her ex is a primary suspect so far, there's a chance she's being held captive somewhere else, whereas the body is of another person.

The question is: how can it be that the body found by the police hints upon the fact that it may be the body of the missing girl, but yet it is unidentifiable at all, or takes very long time to identify?

Comment: If you shift your question wording away from your story line and more towards the methods of identifying an unknown corpse given an initial idea of who it might be, you'll attract fewer close votes.

Comment: If you could define "very long", this question might be answerable. What makes this unusual is that you have a suspect for the victim, most unidentified corpses remain unidentified because the police doesn't know where to start. This would be a story-based answer, but non-cooperating police departments, one finds the corpse and the other one suspects that a murder has taken place or maybe a false clue (some tattoo/clothing that wasn't/was on the corpse that made the police conclude it was/wasn't the girl), but you kind of excluded that possibility. Who links the body to the missing girl?

Comment: PS: It might help if you could tell us the country where this all takes place.

Comment: Check molars with existing dental records, btw what's the point of this question? I can link you details how detective and forensic expert carry out their work but it isn't worldbuilding already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facial recognition is quite low down the scale of reliability. People can look quite similar to those who don't know them.

There are two factors you're looking for though

1. Is she the missing girl? and depending on that answer
2. Who is she?

The first is relatively easy to answer, it's much quicker to identify who someone is not than who they are if you're not expecting to find someone.

#### Dental records, finger prints, DNA.

Those are the major factors that can be picked up from official records. For personal identification you'll also have options on moles, tattoos, scars, bunions, clothing and other secondary identifying features. Again, using these factors finding that she's not the right girl can be done quite quickly.

**Finding out who she is, positive identification, is much harder than finding out who she isn't.**

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this may be *slightly* too story-based, but anyway... in this day in age, I don't think the situation you're looking for can actually happen, for one reason: **We have DNA tests.**

If the police are looking for the missing woman, and they find a woman's body nearby, they **will** run a DNA test to see if it's who they're looking for. If the woman's DNA isn't already in a database, they'll check it against, say, a hair from her hairbrush.

You can prevent immediate identification by cutting the head and hands off the corpse (prevents visual ID, fingerprint matching, or checking against dental records), but then they'll just run a DNA test anyway. So you can only delay the identification for as long as it takes for that DNA test to come back.

This assumes, of course, that the body *is* that of the missing woman. If it isn't, and the DNA doesn't match anyone in the database, it may well remain unidentified for some time.